# Skipping over invalid XML characters with NSXMLParser

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsxmlparser

When an an NSXMLParser encounters an invalid character, it calls the delegate method

```
parser:parseErrorOccurred:
```

from the documentation:

> When this method is invoked, parsing is stopped. For further
>   information about the error, you can query parseError or you can send
>   the parser a parserError message. You can also send the parser
>   lineNumber and columnNumber messages to further isolate where the
>   error occurred. Typically you implement this method to display
>   information about the error to the user.

my question:

is there a way to use the line number and column number to remove the the invalid characters? (perhaps by somehow stripping everything from the current location up until the next closed bracket)? I am in search of a device side solution to receiving invalid XML.

Any thoughts?